# Cant get ajax form data to submit with nodemailer

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Good Morning Everyone,
I have made a web app using node.js and express. I got Nodemailer to send an email and my AJAX is sending the parsed JSON data to express, but I am having trouble getting that from data into nodemailer. My Ajax is sending the JSON to express I have confirmed that with DEV Tools, but I'm at a loss on how to put the JSON into nodemailer. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
/* contact Route: contact.js */
var express = require('express');
const contact = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

contact.use(bodyParser.json() );
contact.use(express.static(__dirname + 'portfolio'));

contact.get('/contact',  (req,res,next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../html-files', 'contact.html'));
  console.log('this works');
});



contact.post('/contact', (req,res) => {



  /*const data = req.body.data;
const from = data.email;
const text = data.message;*/


  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'augustshah@02pilot.com',
      pass: 'hgahalzecelxdxis'
    }
  });
  
  var mailOptions = {
    from: this.email,
    to: 'augustshah@02pilot.com',
    subject: 'Quote',
    text: this.message
  };
  
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
  
})







module.exports = contact;



/* Jquery: script.js*/
//const { json } =  require("body-parser");
//var requirejs = require('requirejs');
//const { json } = require("body-parser");




$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const name = $("#name").val();
    const email = $("#email").val();
    const message = $("#message").val();
    
    var $form = $( this ),
    url = $form.attr( "action", "/contact");

    const data = {
        name: name, 
        email: email,
        message: message
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "/contact", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType: "json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data: JSON.stringify(data), //Form variables
        success: function() {
             alert("Your Email has been sent");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Your Email has not sent. Try Again. ");
        }
    
    })

    
});
```

Comment: you mean turn json in to string? JSON.stringify()

Comment: I did that in my ajax.

Comment: When I go into Dev tools it returns the form data as: {"name":"John","email":"test@gmail.com","message":"this is parsed"}:

Comment: you should get all your values in req.body no need to access .data.

Comment: var mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.email,
    to: 'augustshah@02pilot.com',
    subject: 'Quote',
    text: req.body.message
  };  When I submitted the form it sent the email without the form data.

Comment: I also put a JSON.stringify() in my Jquery and also in my .post in express

Comment: so the receiver receive an email without body?

Comment: Yes, If you look at the original code of Mailoptions above, when I send an email it only sends with the 2 strings: Subject and To and nothing else

Comment: i would check the transport in this case. // verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
  }
}); ref : https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Comment: Alright Ill check that out, I appreciate it.

Comment: I put in the verify method and its logging no error, it says the server is ready. \

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: It was simple. in my script.js, I didn't have my contentType set. I set it to 'application/json' and that fixed my issue.